# Python - DRF returns number of rows but not the data or structure

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i'm new in Python and Django programming and i have this issue with a test API that i'm doing for learning purposes. My problem is that when i make a get request to my API i got the following response:

```
[
    {},
    {}
]
```

The directory hierarchy of my app is this (as you can see, i've created a module for my django Models)

```
── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
├── adapters.py
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── managers.py
├── migrations
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── car.py
├── serializers.py
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

so, in models/**init** i have:

```
from .car import *
```

in models/car.py:

```
class Size(models.Model):
description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
width = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

in serializers.py:

```
class SizeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
class Meta:
    model = Size
    fields = ['description']
```

in views.py:

```
class SizeList(APIView):
def get(self, request, format=None):
    size = Size.objects.all()
    serializer = SizeSerializer(size, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

In my db table i have 2 records and the app is returning 2 empty objects, i assume that the connection to my db is working ok because when i had just one, the API was returning just 1 empty object. What can be causing this? I have an implementation of a user authentication using allauth in this same project and it's working just fine, but when i try to implement these custom models i'm just not having the correct response. Thanks for your help!

PS: Sorry for my English, i'm chilean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ModelSerializer`

```
class SizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `class SizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)`

The difference between `Serializers` and `ModelSerializer` is basically:

The ModelSerializer class is the same as a regular Serializer class, except that:

- It will automatically generate a set of fields for you, based on the model.
- It will automatically generate validators for the serializer, such as unique_together validators.
- It includes simple default implementations of .create() and .update().

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer